# Car garage simulator- Generate random poisson distribution

Tags: python, processing, jython

Below is my code for the car garage simulator I am building. What I am stuck with is, being able to generate cars to drive to certain one garage (garage1) until that garage gets full and then the generated cars to drive to the second garage.

Since I wanted my simulation to work randomly on time. I have to use some kind of poisson distribution to generate the cars somehow. But I cannot seem to get any inspiration on how to generate them and get them to move to the other if the first garage is busy. 
(In this, I only have one garage, which is the goal)

```
 class People(object):
       def __init__(self,c,xpos,ypos,speed,xgoal,ygoal):
           self.c=c
           self.xpos=xpos
           self.ypos=ypos
           self.speed=speed
           self.xgoal=xgoal
           self.ygoal=ygoal

      def show(self):
          #stroke(0)
          fill(self.c)
          rectMode(CENTER)
          rect(self.xpos,self.ypos,20,10)

    def drive(self):
        self.xpos=self.xpos + (self.xgoal - self.xpos)*0.05 * self.speed
        self.ypos=self.ypos + (self.ygoal - self.ypos)*0.05 * self.speed

    person1=People(color(255,0,0),35,280,1,120,10)
    person2=People(color(0,255,0),60,280,1,300,15)

def setup():
    size(450,320)

def draw():
    person1.show()
    person1.drive()
    person2.show()
    person2.drive()
```

Comment: I added the Jython tag (since that is what the Python mode in Processing is running on). It does seem that NumPy can't be directly called from Jython. There might be some Jython library for generating random variables which you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure Python answer to the question in your title (which seems only loosely related to your overall question):

```
import random, math

def poisson(rate):
     t = 0
     count = 0
     while t < 1:
          t -= math.log(random.random())/rate
          count += 1
     return count - 1
```

This answer uses the fact that if events are arriving with exponentially-distributed interarrival time with a certain rate, then the number of arrivals in a given unit of time follows a Poisson distribution at the same rate. While it wouldn't be as fast as a numpy solution, it is still reasonably fast. I was able to generate 100,000 samples with rate = 10 in less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy can draw random samples from a Poisson distribution.  For a given mean and number of samples, you can use

```
import numpy as np

mean = 5
N = 100

samples = np.random.poisson(lam=mean, size=N)
```

Comment: I  am not sure I can use  numpy  in Processing can I ? I think I can code this in python. should  the person be called sample? this is where I am very confused...